# Java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Matt"

Tags: java, file

I've been stuck on this problem for a while now and can't seem to figure out a solution involving a save/load in a file "tictactie_save.txt". Here is my Tic-Tac-Toe `class Multiplayer` code:

```
//Creates a new 3x3 Array grid.
char[][] ticTacToeBoard = new char[3][3];

//Runs Multiplayer.
public void multiplayer() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String p1 = "", p2 = "";
    int currRound = 0;
    String loadOption;

    //Default as not used.
    boolean fileUsed = false;
    // Ask the user if they want to load a saved game
    System.out.print("Do you want to load a saved game? (y/n): ");
    loadOption = input.next();

    //If user wants to load file.
    if (loadOption.substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
        String loadFile = "tictactoe_save.txt";
        try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(loadFile))) {
            fileUsed = true;
            currRound = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine()); // Load the current round number
            p1 = reader.nextLine();
            p2 = reader.nextLine();
            turn = reader.nextLine().charAt(0);
            System.out.println(p1 + ", " + p2 + ", " + turn + ", " + currRound); //For testing
            displayBoard(ticTacToeBoard);
            for (int i = 0; i < ticTacToeBoard.length; i++) {
                String[] row = reader.nextLine().split(" ");
                for (int j = 0; j < Math.min(ticTacToeBoard[0].length, row.length); j++) {
                    ticTacToeBoard[i][j] = row[i].charAt(0);
                }
            }

            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: File not found.");
        }
    }
    if (!fileUsed) {
        //If user does not want to load a save file.
        System.out.println("*Multiplayer active*");
        System.out.print("Enter your name, Player 1: ");
        p1 = input.next();
        System.out.print("Enter your name, Player 2: ");
        p2 = input.next();
        System.out.println("\nLets play! Your goal is to get three-in-a-row \nwith your pieces to win the game! "
                + "Ties can occure, so be smart! \nPlayer 1 plays X pieces; Player 2 plays O pieces. Have fun!");
        //Displays board.
        displayBoard(ticTacToeBoard);

        currRound = 0;
    }

    String currPlayer = p1;
    
    //Game runs
    for (int round = currRound; round < 9; round++) {

        //User selects and places a piece that is legal.
        selectArea_Human(ticTacToeBoard, turn, currPlayer);

        //Updates ticTacToeBoard.
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
        updateBoard(ticTacToeBoard);

        //Checks if three-in-a-row has occured.
        if (isThree_In_A_Row(turn, ticTacToeBoard)) {
            break;
        }

        //Next players turn.
        turn = (turn == 'X') ? 'O' : 'X';
        currPlayer = (turn == 'X') ? p1 : p2;

        // Save the game state to a file after every turn.
        String saveFile = "tictactoe_save.txt";
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(saveFile)) {
            writer.write(p1 + "\n"); // Save p1 name.
            writer.write(p2 + "\n"); // Save p2 name.
            writer.write(currRound + "\n"); // Save the current round number
            writer.write(turn + "\n"); // Save the current turn.
            for (int i = 0; i < ticTacToeBoard.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < ticTacToeBoard[0].length; j++) {
                    writer.write(ticTacToeBoard[i][j] + " ");
                }
                writer.write("\n");
            }
            System.out.println("Game successfully saved.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: File not found.");
        }
    }

    //Checks for tie game; Otherwise declares the winner.
    if (!isThree_In_A_Row(turn, ticTacToeBoard)) {
        System.out.println("The game is over.");
        System.out.println("It's a tie!");
    } else {
        winner = currPlayer;
        System.out.println("The game is over.");
        System.out.println("The winner is " + winner + "!");
    }
}
```

Here is my output:

```
Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe game! Select a Mode you would like to play.
------------------------------
The Modes are: 
 1. Player Vs Player.
 2. Player Vs Computer.
 3. Computer Vs Computer.
>> 1
Do you want to load a saved game? (y/n): Yes
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Matt"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
        at Multiplayer.multiplayer(Multiplayer.java:41)
        at TicTacToe.MUltiplayer_Game(TicTacToe.java:107)
        at TicTacToe.main(TicTacToe.java:38)
```

What it's supposed to do is after completing the player's turn, save the game and continue the game until the user ends the program. I've tested this in NetBeans Debug and everything appeared to be saving correctly.
How can I fix this error so that it can properly load after running? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like your trying to parse an integer from a string somewhere that is not a number string its matt.

Comment: The code that writes the file puts the players’ names as the first two lines, then the current round. The code that reads the file expects the current round to come before the two names.

Comment: @TimMoore, So should I move `currRound` after `p1` and `p2`? Edit: I swaped the `currRound` and it worked. I guees the write and reader files need to be exactly identical to each other.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It’s the same file, so the format the data is written with needs to match what it expects to read.